# Django ImportError: No module named urls

Tags: python, django, url, import, module

I'm adding a plugin for my project by installing it through pip. Since the plugin has its own urls file (and is located in `virtual environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages`), it somehow conflicts with the main urls file and `ImportError: No module named urls` error gets printed out. As I binged it, there's something with `ROOT_URLCONF` setting, but that is all ok unless I've included the given plugin in my global `urls.py` file, like so: `url(r'^plugin/', get_plugin_pattern()),`.

What can I do to mend it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your plugin into your settings.py file's in Installed Apps section looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    "yourplugin",
    ...
)
```

And changed your urls.py file looks like:

```
url(r'^plugin/', include('yourplugin.urls')),
```

Comment: what's the name of that plugin?